# Execution order of callables is not consistent

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, callable

I have this code where I execute sets of callables, I need one set to finish all it's work before triggering the next set. This code seems to work fine but sometimes next set would start running before time. What is wrong here?

```
private void executeSubGraph(QuestExecutionContext ctx, Set<Activity> subGraph, int progressAfterRan) {
    ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(16);
    subGraph.forEach(a -> {
        ActivityRunner<? extends Activity> runner = activityRunnerFactory.getRunner(ctx, a);
        if (runner != null) {
            Callable<List<PortValuePart>> runnerCallable = () -> {
                try {
                    LOG.info("Running {} in {}", a, a.getClass() );
                    List<PortValuePart> result = runner.call();
                    LOG.info("Result of {} in {} is {}", a, a.getClass(), result);
                    if (result != null) {
                        result.forEach(r -> resultProcessor.processResult(new PortValuePartEnvelope(r)));
                    }
                    return result;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    LOG.warn("Exception for {} in {}", a, runner.getClass(), e);
                    resultProcessor.processResult(Progress.failed(ctx.getId(), e));
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            };
            Future<List<PortValuePart>> p = pool.submit(runnerCallable);
        } else {
            LOG.warn("No runner found for activity {}", a);
            resultProcessor.processResult(Progress.failed(ctx.getId(), new RuntimeException("No runner found for activity " + a)));
            throw new RuntimeException("No runner found for activity " + a);
        }
    });

    pool.shutdown();

    try {
        pool.awaitTermination(WAIT_TIME_MILLIS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        resultProcessor.processResult(Progress.running(ctx.getId(), progressAfterRan));
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        throw new PlatformException("Execution interrupted.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that [`ExecutorService.awaitTermination`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#awaitTermination(long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) doesn't throw an exception if it times out; it just returns `false`. If you want to make sure that the next calls don't run concurrently with these ones, you should probably use the return value, and maybe throw an exception (and kill the tasks) if it's taking way too long.